# How to implement color selector of TextView when the OnClick listener is set on its parent Layout?

Tags: android

The layout xml is as below. I have a RelativeLayout, which contains a TextView. The OnClick listener is set on RelativeLayout. The RelativeLayout has a selector background. What I want is, when user clicks on the RelativeLayout, the background of the RelativeLayout should change, and the color of the text of the TextView should change too. Even though I set color selector for the TextView, only the selector on RelativeLayout works. The color selector on TextView doesn't work. How can I implement change of both RelativeLayout background and text color of TextView when user clicks the layout? Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/mytextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@drawable/color_blue_selector" 
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?  I am having the same problem but i am not able to get the textview to change its color when the parent was clicked. The parent background can be changed but the child textview text color cant!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at android:duplicateParentState: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:duplicateParentState.

Btw, this question is also answered here: [TextView color change on focus/press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360297/textview-color-change-on-focus-press)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just to

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.brown);
textView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```

... having brown and white defined in res/values/color.xml defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="brown">#2E2B27</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps  you could use `OnTouchListener` and respond on Down and Up events changing the text color

Comment: This assumes that you'd like the color to be changed while the layout is being clicked

Comment: Yes, the assumption stands. But this approach is kind of complicated to implement. I just wonder whether Android has a good way to support this feature.