# TextView color change on focus/press

Tags: android, colors, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a some ui widgets including textview inside RelativeLayout which is clickable. My problem is textview text color does not change when relativelayout gets focus although I have set textview color property correctly.

Is there any easy way to cascade focus to childview inside relative layout, same as listview items.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_white_blue"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_med"
        android:textColor="@color/black_text_white_focused"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Movie Name"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify `android:duplicateParentState='true'` on your `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically by  `textView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);`

for your

`TextView textView= new TextView(this);`